# Does Karate framework supports IOS app testing if yes could some one please provide an example?

Tags: karate

Does Karate framework supports IOS app testing if yes could some one please provide an example and documentatio, have tried searching i was not able to find the doc and example ?

Answer (score 1):

It does through Appium. You can find an example and links to the documentation here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/examples/mobile-test

Comment: @Thomos it has Android example  does it work for ios as well. Do i just need to change  the type  over here to ios  like this ?* configure driver = { type: 'ios ', webDriverPath : "/wd/hub", start: false, httpConfig : { readTimeout: 120000 }}

Comment: @vishnu if that's what the docs say, yes

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas i will try this option